# python - ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (3,)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having an image "img_carree" that I would like to change (of size 427x427, each pixel carry the RGB value)

```
M = np.array(img_carree)
M.shape                #return(427,427,3)
```

I also have a color object

```
color = (255,255,0)
```

So I am trying to check for the correlation between each pixels of my image with the color and store it in a new numpy array

```
F = M
for i in range(427):
   for j in range(427):
        F[i][j] = np.corrcoef(M[i][j], np.array(color))
```

But I always run into the problem of "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (3,)"

Anyhow thank you for reading my question

Comment: `F = M` does not make a copy!  `M[i,j]` will be a (3,) shape slot.  `corrcoef` returns a (2,2) array.  Do you understand what `corrcoef` is doing?

Comment: @hpaulj haha I just reread the documentation for `corrcoef` and fixed the problem in 5 mins :D Thank you for reminding me that I didn't know how `corrcoef` work

Answer (score 0):

So `np.corrcoef` return an array of shape (2,2) but `F[i][j]` is of shape (3,). Hence I ran into the problem of "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (3,)"

Thanks to @hpaulij, I read the documentation again and here's my new solution:

```
M = np.array(img_carree)
F = np.empty([427,427])
for i in range(427):
    for j in range(427):
        F[i][j] = np.corrcoef(M[i][j], np.array(color))[0,1]
```

Instead of copying F with M `F = M`, I declared F as an empty array of size 427x427: `F = np.empty([427,427])` 
Then for each element in F, `F[i][j] = np.corrcoef(M[i][j], np.array(color))[0,1]`